# Find maximum sum contiguous subarray such that the length of the subarray is less than equal to k?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, sub-array

If more than two subarrays exist we need to return the subarray that has lesser length.

We are only concerned with length of the subarray and its sum.

I know this can be solved in O(n^2) using  brute force ,but i am looking for a efficient way to do this.
I also  tried solving this in O(n) using the sliding window concept , but i later realized it fails for some cases.

How can this be done efficiently?

Comment: Maybe I'm the only reader who needs this help (or needing it disqualifies me from answering), but what's the input data structure?  An array of numbers?  What's a contiguous subarray?

Comment: @danh The word "contiguous" means neighbouring or adjacent. A contiguous subarray has all its elements adjacent to each other. Like, for an array of 10 elements, a[0], a[1], a[2] make a contiguous subarray, a[0], a[2], a[4] dont

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to look at Kadane's algorithm. It finds a contiguous subarray with the largest sum from a given array. It does so in O(n). Your problem restrains the length to "k". So you simply need to put a check for length <= k in Kadane's.